# Angular tslint setting mistake. ng build: success, ng build --prod: fail

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tsconfig

I can't fix next error: when I build project for production, building is successfull. But when I build project with param --prod it's fail.
Error like this:

```
in node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\antd.d.ts.ɵep.html(1,999): : Object is possibly 'null'.
```

My TSlint setup is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],

    "removeComments": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.ts.ɵin.html"
  ]
}
```

I tried to add node_modules folder to "exclude" but it doesn't work.

Comment: after adding node_modules to sxcluse, are you getting same error?

Comment: What's the version of your TypeScript and which version of ngZorro are you using? Have you checked their GitHub repository for similar issues?

Comment: similar issue , https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/414

Comment: NagaSaiA, yes, I get the same error
Roy, I don't get error from npm. I think if I had a problem with semantic version my build for develop would be fail too

Comment: And I'ts happens because I try to write in "strict: true" mode